# How to combine rows of df using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conda, nan

I am trying to concatenate rows of a data frame that contains strings. I want to check if the row contains `NaN` and if so, remove the `NaN` from that row and concatenate the rest with the one above that row. Finally remove the row that contains NaN.

Here is my sample data:

```
df=[["d","t","u","y","e"],["d",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,"o"],["y","p","p","w","r"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
0    1    2    3  4
d   t    u    y   e
d  NaN  NaN  NaN  o
y    p    p    w  r
```

I want the output to look like the one below.

```
   0    1    2    3   4
   dd   t    u    y  eo   
   y    p    p    w   r
```

Here is my trial, but no luck.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
for j in range(len(df.iloc[1,])):
    if(pd.isnull(df.iloc[i,j])==True):
        df.concat(df.iloc[i,j],df.iloc[i-1,j])
        df.dropna(df.iloc[:,i])
```

I am new to Python, can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create helper `Series` for grouping.

So first create mask for all rows with at least one `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), create `Series` by constructor, replace non match values to `NaN`s by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and back filling missing values for same groups above with `limit=1` for replace only one row above.

Last replace all missing values to empty values, grouping and aggregate `join`:

```
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)
s = pd.Series(np.arange(len(m)), index=df.index)
g = s.where(m).bfill(limit=1).fillna(s)

df = df.fillna('').groupby(g).agg(''.join).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    0  1  2  3   4
0  dd  t  u  y  eo
1   y  p  p  w   r
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt help. This works fine. I spent hours to figure this out.